# What are the Windows 10 universal app deployment methods?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm trying to evaluate Windows 10 universal app platform for future development, and trying to understand how Windows 10 universal apps can be deployed to Windows 10 computers.

Are they can be deployed only via the Windows Store, just like Windows 8 Metro apps? Or can they be deployed via an MSI or similar installer, like a normal WinAPI application can?

Comment: I would say like Win8 Apps. Wait for the RTM and the final docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 Universal apps are deployed essentially the same as Windows 8 apps. Either can be deployed through the store or side-loaded via PowerShell or a device management tool such as Intune.

See [Deploying enterprise apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx) in the Windows Dev Center.

Windows 10 does have (or will have) a different method than Windows 8.1 to enable side-loading. See the future approach comments in [Enable your device for development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn706236.aspx?#FutureApproach), which addresses both development and general purpose side-loading via the Update & Security Settings control panel.

Comment: Also check out [this //build talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-695) - about 14:20 minutes in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, let's say I'm a software developer wanting to distribute an app outside of the Store. My installer modifies that setting (enables sideloading, with user consent). Is it something akin to disabling UAC during an install (a big no-no), or something considered a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: This is a user / admin setting. I'd look askance at an installer which tried to force this.